# Open .ui file from Linux on Windows

Tags: qt, cross-platform, qt-designer

My colleague created a C++ Qt Project on Linux and I "transposed" it on Windows. Now, I am a functional GUI but I don't know why, when I open the *.ui* file with QtDesigner, the file is empty, all widgets disappeared.

Any idea how to get back my widgets or is it only because the file was created on QtDesigner on Linux ?

Here is a part of the ui file opened on Windows with a text editor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>874</width>
    <height>497</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>110</y>
      <width>541</width>
      <height>331</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="maximumSize">
     <size>
      <width>860</width>
      <height>700</height>
     </size>
    </property>
    <property name="currentIndex">
     <number>1</number>
    </property>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="buildMotionTab_3">
     <attribute name="title">
      <string>Tab 1</string>
     </attribute>
     <widget class="QFrame" name="centralFrame_3">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>-10</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <width>860</width>
        <height>851</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="minimumSize">
       <size>
        <width>860</width>
        <height>851</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="maximumSize">
       <size>
        <width>810</width>
        <height>851</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
      <widget class="QFrame" name="motorFrameP_3">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>260</x>
         <y>10</y>
         <width>281</width>
         <height>280</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Minimum">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="minimumSize">
        <size>
         <width>250</width>
         <height>280</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="maximumSize">
        <size>
         <width>300</width>
         <height>280</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="frameShape">
        <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="frameShadow">
        <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
       </property>
       <widget class="QSpinBox" name="LineDist">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>190</x>
          <y>150</y>
          <width>81</width>
          <height>32</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="minimum">
         <number>1</number>
        </property>
        <property name="maximum">
         <number>470</number>
        </property>
        <property name="singleStep">
         <number>1</number>
        </property>
        <property name="value">
         <number>50</number>
        </property>
       </widget>
   [...]
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="StandDownButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>30</y>
      <width>101</width>
      <height>31</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>StandDown</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="Homing1Button">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>120</x>
      <y>70</y>
      <width>101</width>
      <height>31</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Homing X</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>874</width>
     <height>25</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: A .ui file is just a text file that you should be able to open with another editor on either linux or windows. Check that whatever you are doing to transfer it isn't blasting the file, because the file itself should be cross platform.

Comment: could you show the `.ui` file (right click and open it in plain text mode, copy and paste in your question)

Comment: What exactly does "translated" mean, and why did you think it was necessary to do that?

Comment: I used the wrong word sorry (my translation was bad), and it is more "transpose" than "translate". I just copy all files on Linux, and on windows create a Qt Project on Visual Studio and add all these files to this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like some thing went wrong in transporting the file (I can't say, but could be copy was done in binary mode? or some lines were not expanded in case you copied and pasted the text ..)

The `ui` xml you shared is broken at line 127 where it shows `[...]` which is not valid, in place of this it should show closing xml tags for `</widget>` , I think 4 closing tags  `</widget>` are missing, then it should be ok.

[image]

Comment: It is because the xml as too many characters to be write in my post, so I resume by [...] but not a the good place it seems ^^

Comment: @MathieuGauquelin The good news is: I used whatever code you shared and it worked!